# Debug the error

Tags: c

I have created a code to find the `largest number`.
I have an error in main function. It says **syntax error before t**.
 Please correct my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main(){
  int a[100],n,i,t;
  printf("enter the array size");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  printf("enter the array elements");
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
     scanf("%d",&a[i]);
  }
  t=0;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
     if (a[i]t){
        t=a[i];
     }
  }
  printf("the maximum number is %d",t);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, this - `if (a[i]t)` - makes no sense. But you will have to "correct" it yourself.

Comment: Check the return value of ` scanf `

Comment: Indent your code please, it will be easily to read and you could find your error yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax error is at following line

```
if (a[i]t){
```

Use

```
if (a[i]>t)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have an little mistake in conditional statement**

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    if (a[i]>t){ /*Your error is in this line, You missed greater than sign*/
        t=a[i];       
    }
}
```